# Breach In Java Runtime (A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment)

Tags: java, backend, runtime-environment

I am currently trying to open a serial port to send some data to a chip, but I get the error fatal error has been detected by the java runtime environment. Here is the Console log.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=21920, tid=23116
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (14.0.2+12) (build 14.0.2+12)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

The Function that is causing the error is supposed to open  a port for backend/board communications. Here is the function

```
public boolean openPort() throws SerialPortException {
        if(portOpened){
            throw new SerialPortException(portName, "openPort()", SerialPortException.TYPE_PORT_ALREADY_OPENED);
        }
        if(portName != null){
            boolean useTIOCEXCL = (System.getProperty(SerialNativeInterface.PROPERTY_JSSC_NO_TIOCEXCL) == null &&
                                   System.getProperty(SerialNativeInterface.PROPERTY_JSSC_NO_TIOCEXCL.toLowerCase()) == null);
            portHandle = serialInterface.openPort(portName, useTIOCEXCL);//since 2.3.0 -> (if JSSC_NO_TIOCEXCL defined, exclusive lock for serial port will be disabled)
        }
        else {
            throw new SerialPortException(portName, "openPort()", SerialPortException.TYPE_NULL_NOT_PERMITTED);//since 2.1.0 -> NULL port name fix
        }
        if(portHandle == SerialNativeInterface.ERR_PORT_BUSY){
            throw new SerialPortException(portName, "openPort()", SerialPortException.TYPE_PORT_BUSY);
        }
        else if(portHandle == SerialNativeInterface.ERR_PORT_NOT_FOUND){
            throw new SerialPortException(portName, "openPort()", SerialPortException.TYPE_PORT_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        else if(portHandle == SerialNativeInterface.ERR_PERMISSION_DENIED){
            throw new SerialPortException(portName, "openPort()", SerialPortException.TYPE_PERMISSION_DENIED);
        }
        else if(portHandle == SerialNativeInterface.ERR_INCORRECT_SERIAL_PORT){
            throw new SerialPortException(portName, "openPort()", SerialPortException.TYPE_INCORRECT_SERIAL_PORT);
        }
        portOpened = true;
        return true;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated!!

p.s. this is my first post, so feedback on post formatting would also be appreciated, if you have the time

Thank you
Marbull

Comment: If don't have any native code libraries of your own or in other jar dependencies (you don't specify), it is often worth re-running with a later JDK version when you get EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.